# webpack: new css-loader 4.0.0 tries to load fonts (make them embded); how to disable this?

Tags: webpack, font-face, webpack-4, css-loader

In my styles I have such font-faces definition:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), 
        url(/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'), 
        url(/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'), 
        url(/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

After I have updated  `css-loader` to new version 4.0.0 (released several days ago)  I got those errors (bulding bundle):

> ERROR in ./src/index.scss Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js): Error: Can't resolve
> '/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2' in
> 'D:\cot\EDelivery\EDelivery\EDelivery.Injected.AspCore.RegWebApp\src'
> at doResolve (D:\cot\EDelivery\EDelivery\EDelivery.Injected.AspCore.RegWebApp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:209:21)
> at hook.callAsync (D:\cot\EDelivery\EDelivery\EDelivery.Injected.AspCore.RegWebApp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5)
> at _fn0 (eval at create (D:\cot\EDelivery\EDelivery\EDelivery.Injected.AspCore.RegWebApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10),
> :15:1)

It looks like in new version `css-loader` tries to make fonts embded. How to disable this behaviour? (Can't find the option there: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/ )

My configuration is:

```
{
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            },
            { // ... postcss-loader, sass-loader
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of loader: "css-loader", you can pass extra params like this to disable the feature.
`"css-loader?url=false"`

Answer (score 1):

Add `url: false` option to css and scss loaders. It will disable parsing paths of fonts and images in your [css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader#url) and it won`t pack them in build.

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.scss$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          // Do not parse paths specified in url() and image-set to not include fonts to build
          url: false
        },
      },
      'sass-loader'
    ],
  },
],
},
```